# how to append html code to the NSString variable in iphone

Tags: iphone, view, port

i have htmlString of string type.i want to append the view port code to this variable.How to do this?is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
NSString *str3 = [str1 stringByAppendingString: str2];
```